# Ruby - Test whether database connection is possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am looking to implement a way to test the database connection for our application.

We are currently having connectivity issues and therefore want to be able to check connectivity without having to login.

Is there a way to display a page stating database connection is up or database connection is down dependent upon whether connection fails. If any additional information is needed please let me know.

Only beginning to learn the ropes so apologies if I'm short on detail.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check if the connection is possible by running the following script:

```
require './config/environment.rb' # Assuming the script is located in the root of the rails app
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection # Establishes connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection # Calls connection object
  puts "CONNECTED!" if ActiveRecord::Base.connected? 
  puts "NOT CONNECTED!" unless ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
rescue
  puts "NOT CONNECTED!"
end
```

Comment: Just a heads-up to never use `rescue` without actual name of error you are expecting. The code above would output "Not connected!" if you had any error, making it impossible to debug anything. I'd recommend to rescue from specific errors like `rescue ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified`

Comment: Yes thats true. Its a very pragmatic approach that only verifies that the database connection can be established. It cant be used to debug it.

Comment: @davidb Thanks for the input. Apologies but i cant locate config/environments.rb. In my config file there are the following files and folders; - apps.rb, boot.rb, deploy.rb, environments.yaml, settings.yaml, warble.rb and folders deploy (contains production.rb and staging.rb) and recipes folder (contains base.rb, nginx.rb, rbenv.rb). In relation to another question i had somebody brought it to my attention that i am using Sinatra. Would this affect my ability to use activerecord as there doesnt seem to be any reference to it in the existing source code.

Comment: We somehow ended up using this code in our rails app as a health check to ensure that postgresql is accessible. However it turned out that `establish_connection` causes a significant memory leak. Removing that line keeps the functionality intact but eliminates the memory leak.

Comment: awesome bro, I learnt a lot