# Using foreman, can we run db migration once the database is started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, foreman

I want to run both the database and migration in `foreman`. However, I found that they usually run at the same time when I start `foreman`. Since at the time I run migration the database has not fully started yet, it causes the migration to fail.

Heroku using `Procfile` could facilitate a release phase. The phase would be run after all the commands are run. Can I do the same using foreman in my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not rely to `Procfile` to maintain the release process. The Heroku build stack does.

Since the `foreman` provides us the way to run multiple processes at the same time, not running processes in order, so your problem is not the responsibility of `foreman`

However, you have some other ways to do so.

1. Simple: since `foreman` can start your process with shell command, you can use basic shell command `sleep` (in seconds) for delaying your process

   ```
   db_process: start_db_script.sh
   migrarion_process: sleep 5; bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
   ```
2. Full control: Instead of run default migration rake task, you can write another rake task which check the connection to database before execute the migration ( refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170025/ruby-test-whether-database-connection-is-possible?answertab=active#tab-top))

   ```
   retried = 0
   begin
     # Establishes connection
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
     # Try to reconnect
     # It will raise error if cannot reach your database
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect! 
     Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
   rescue => e 
     retried += 1
     if retried <= 5 # Retry only 5 times
       sleep 1       # Wait 1 seconds before retry
       retry
     end
     puts "#{e} Cannot connect to your database with 5 seconds"
   end
   ```